# Как извлечь необходимые элементы из iFrame?

Tags: css, iframe, javascript

Есил просто подкоючаю виджет вконтакте, то не с css, ни с js манипулировать элементами не удается. 
Может можно как-нибудь загрузить как-нибудь к себе на хостинг, а потом достать оттуда необходимые элементы?
ПОдскажите, как это можно сделать.

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гораздо проще делать всё это с помощью метода `.contents()` в `jquery`, только учтите, что делается это всё в пределах одного сайта (домена, сервера).

Например, чтобы получить содержимое блока `#block_in_frame` в фрейме `#my_iframe`:

```
$('#my_iframe').contents().find('#block_in_frame').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

fopen`ом открываем ссылку, циклом находим нужное нам, забираем выводим.

Comment: Хотя в данной ситуации это вряд ли удастся, задача для меня не ясна...

Answer (score 1):

Родительский фрейм не может управлять дочерним. Политика безопасности. Ведь зафреймить можно всё что угодно.

Comment: В рамках одного сайта можно, в других же будет ошибка, связаная с политикой безопасности браузеров.

Answer (score -1):

Скопируйте код фрейма в новый файл, залейте на хостинг и include'ом вставьте куда надо. Попробуйте, может сработает!

Comment: Необходимо подгружать друзей(людей) для каждого человека своих.

Comment: @Радик Камалов , какой именно виджет?

Comment: мы вконтакте